# TS optional and required generic union types

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, typescript-generics

#### Goal

I am trying to create an optional parameter unless a type has been supplied making it required.

#### Expected Behaviour

I want the following `get` method to have an optional parameter by default. If the `get` method is called and provided a type as TT, the method should then have a required parameter of type TT.

```
export class Test<T = void> {

    get<TT>(param: T & TT): Test<T & TT>
    get<TT>(param: void | TT): Test<T & TT>
    get<TT>(param: T & TT): Test<T & TT> {
        return null as any;
    }

}

const test = new Test();

test.get();

test
    .get<{ name: string }>({ name: '' })
    .get() // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
    .get<{ age: number }>({ age: 23 }); // Property 'name' is missing in type '{ age: number; }' but required in type '{ name: string; }'
```

The code above will compile, but I want it to throw the errors mentioned in the comments. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285906/infer-parameter-types-in-function-chain

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 20 September 2021**

It requires a bit of typescript gymnastic.

Consider this example.

Explanation is in comments

```js
class Test<T = void> {

    /**
     * If T is void (is not provided)
     * we dont expect any arguments,
     * hence 
     * 
     * But if T is provided - expect T as an argument
     * and return Test<T> respectfuly
     */
    get<U extends {
        0: 'T is void',
        1: 'T is provided'
    }[T extends void ? 0 : 1]>(
        ...param: (
            U extends 'T is provided'
            ? [T]
            : []
        )
    ):
        U extends 'T is provided' ? Test<T> : Test
    /**
     * If T extends void - argument should
     * have U type
     * If T provided and it is pseudo equal U - expect T & U
     * If T provided and it is a subtype of U - expect T
     * If T is provided and it is not a subtype of U - expect T & U
     */
    get<U>(
        ...param: (T extends void
            ? [U]
            : T extends U
            ? (U extends T
                ? [T & U]
                : [T]
            )
            : [T & U]
        )
    ): Test<U>
    /**
     * Default types
     */
    get<U>(...param: Partial<U[]>) {
        return null as any
    }

}

const test = new Test(); // ok

test.get() // ok

const result = test
    .get<{ name: string }>({ name: '' }) // ok
    .get() // error Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
    .get<{ age: number }>({ age: 23 }); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeW0C80BuB7AlgCYB80A3gLABQ10d0A9AFRO33RPQCSAZnNPhh4i0ABSDoAO1xJoABwBOubEXiEAlG3qcA7vGiFck2fAAec%20MFlhJAT2hgFAcwCuAW3jGIAGi11OABaewPp%20HNBhnABCLrL4fOgSisqqhNAAtNBmFlb8kA6SDs7unkiRBWkK8EguCoUIyGikVRA5SDwuILaRDH5O1SgAqlmmSJ6EMJRU7OwADABc0ADkiUIEhEu%200zN0AIyLKwIwySqEakt%20AL4A2uhmY5ITOOvQAPzQs9CLuwC6xKJhegAOhBckcYDciwB2x27GG93GMEOSSUp3OgJ271uPwxM0W1xxMJmmiJ6nmuPho0Ry1W8lRqSWbzgiFQsFIiwaZSJzFYRPCvH4CMeaxEmUcrg8xmgEACuE6hHKATA2H0wyQtgs5QF6BOqQqAjixwg8BchiyAEcXGAQNBhplspZZOgAGS2rUJOkpM5pGxpfCGhzSlwAI3VFmguD4dpGbTg7v4KK9an1-qOUhkgYgIbD%20kjtoyMcd-Fdgx6fQGg3%20uJBQLBCghULuVOFzyIuPYWMGhNheMFzaepb5sPeokpDyesHbw%20gt2gJe7Pdh%20NgC8X0BJa7oy7nttXxL8ZOZjUrfh55QAIvAeGBOrIcxAy0T%20qhK6Ia3WG9AAAqOJD4a1DASxDqOQuJVDUdRSJ0Nr5DY3REpc1DUIhNBUMARjINAYyYVgkjwDoR5IKI6gANxIVQDAMIRKDCCQQLPigABEtK0Yx-yHpyNHrKQ1DYUg9HVMRjBUbgADW5HoZImEtLemBYSyfgCagZBSBC8CLMgCj4JITjQJc-wqZIakHIylwbsCz5CZR0AAKLmI6ya7EUEqlD40DBrE0BOBmsxAopDEqWA-SLJI7jBvACh6QZDjBdAABMADMemkUAA)

I made my own assumptions about certain requirements. If it does not meet your requirements, please provide more into your question.

For now, this answer technically meets your goal

Comment: That required parameter by default is the main problem I am trying to solve. I don't want the parameter to be required by default, only when the type has been specified. Thanks for trying though.