# Infer parameter types in function chain

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a home made function mapping chain. Thing is, I want to make sure typing stays consistent trough the mapping chain. My problem is that I don't know how to write `f(x:T) => U`

For a proper example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
function myChainer<T>(args:T){
    return {
       map:(innerFuction:(payload: T) => unknown){
           return myChainer(innerFuction(args))
       }
    }
}
```

Now, if I run

```js
myChainer(0)
.map((args1) => {
    return doSomething(args1) ? "a" : "b"
})
.map((args2) => {
    return doSomething2(args2) ? true : false
})
```

The first `map` will know that the type of `args1` is `Number` but the second one wont know that the type of `args2` is `string`. And, as expected, subsequent chained functions wont know the types of their respective arguments. With what should `unknown` be replaced with so that every chained function figures out the type of its arguments based on the return type of the previously chained function?

Comment: Please share reproducable code

Comment: The second generic type, U, isn't set anywhere. It should be on the map method, so the inner function can be T => U: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4GEAWBDGYCmATgDwAqAfABTaEDmAzgFyKkCUiA3gFCKKH5QQhMN169k2AA7EAquUSU8BQgDFw0eGGaVJ2VABs42ACbM2iALzyZ7UWN79BwlBhx4iisMrWRYCanT0rKwA3DxiAL7hUVFc+gKIxnAAynDIAph4tNo0DMxgIMgARkTsVohFcHDx2GBh8VCJKWkZWQBMOYHM9FCEWWXyldX4tWFcaFi4ypQADKxcAHQSkpQBDACMA5zhDgJCSEmp6VCZYLRr9JuIAPyIAETYd4jMd0V3XBHzS1KrufRtWzsuycB2ax1OtDaFwBN0QvRA+GeiGA2H09HwH1YQA.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Where should ```U``` be set? I would want to set it somewhere in ```myChainer``` so that all new mapped functions can infer the types of the parameters from the return value of the previous function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a generic type parameter to refer to whatever the return type of the `innerFunction` is, so that you can then provide that type to TS when you recursively refer to `myChainer`.

Here is what that would look like:

```js
function myChainer<T>(args:T){
    return {
       map<U>(innerFuction:(payload: T) => U) {
           return myChainer<U>(innerFuction(args))
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have:

```js
function myChainer<T>(args: T) {
    return {
        map: <R,>(innerFuction: (payload: T) => R) => {
            return myChainer(innerFuction(args))
        }
    }
}

const foo = (arg: number) => arg.toString()
const bar = (arg: string) => Promise.resolve(parseInt(arg, 10))
const baz = (arg: Promise<number>) => arg


const result = myChainer(0)
    .map(arg => foo(arg)) // arg -> number
    .map(arg => bar(arg)) // arg -> string
    .map(arg => baz(arg)) // arg -> Promise<number>
    .map(arg => foo(arg)) // expected error
```

Comment: @GregL was faster )